# Capacitor storage timing issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, local-storage

I'm trying to obtain Storage data within a function which returns a constant. However, when the storage is not set, different data should be used instead.

The issue I'm running into is that the "other" data is used, as the storage has not yet returned the info.

Moving the entire function within the .then() causes the issue: "A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.ts". I can't figure out how this should be resolved.

```
generateMap(id: string, zoom: number): L.Map {
  let current_position = {
    latitude: 52.3702157,
    longitude: 4.8951679
  }

  Storage.get({ key: 'current_position' }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value != null) {
      current_position = JSON.parse(result.value);
    }
  });

  const map = L.map(id,
    {
      zoom: zoom,
      center: latLng({ lat: current_position.latitude, lng: current_position.longitude }),
    });

  return map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return your `Promise` from the function (and with it, change the return type):

```js
generateMap(id: string, zoom: number): Promise<L.Map> {
  let current_position = {
    latitude: 52.3702157,
    longitude: 4.8951679
  }

  return Storage.get({ key: 'current_position' }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value != null) {
      current_position = JSON.parse(result.value);
    }

    return L.map(id,
    {
      zoom: zoom,
      center: latLng({
        lat: current_position.latitude,
        lng: current_position.longitude
      }),
    });
  });
}
```

Which you will have to call like this:

```js
generateMap(id, zoom).then((map) => {
  // here you'll have your map
});
```

---

You can also use `async/await`, but that's just syntactic sugar, as your return type will always have be a `Promise`, it will however increase code readability:

```js
async generateMap(id: string, zoom: number): Promise<L.Map> {
  const { value } = await Storage.get({ key: 'current_position' });

  const currentPosition = value != null
    ? JSON.parse(value)
    : { latitude: 52.3702157, longitude: 4.8951679 };

  return L.map(id,{
    zoom: zoom,
    center: latLng({
      lat: currentPosition.latitude,
      lng: currentPosition.longitude
    }),
  });
}
```

Comment: I thought the same thing, but the issue "A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.ts" persists using your first method. Thus it doesn't work.

Comment: @S_NoBEl that just means you forgot to add `return` in front of the `Promise`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. the map const is processed further as the function is simplified from reality. You're refering to the return on L.map?

Comment: @S_NoBEl yes I am. You can't continue the function, because whatever is inside the `.then` will be executed after the things you put below it. JavaScript is an async event driven language, and execution order isn't straight forward. You can make it more understandable with the `async/await` notation

Comment: @S_NoBEl so to make it clear, if you look at your code the if statement `if (result.value != null) {` inside the `.then` is executed after `return map;`. That's because you are passing a function in the `.then` call, and this is called when the `Storage.get` resolves, but then the original function already returned

Comment: Okay, so : L.Map is replaced by Promise<L.Map>, that's the only change I see? but again that returns an error still.

Comment: @S_NoBEl I was indeed foolish. I didn't add the return either :D It however was there in the `async/await` example